# function and not using Global

Tags: php, scope

Hi I was wondering if someone could help me out. Ive tried Global but this is not what I want.

```
$i= 0

if(.....){
   echo "In this part";
   $i = 1;
}
else{
   echo "........";
   $i = 2;
}

function process(){
   echo $i;
}
```

Comment: Removed Java tag. This is PHP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wouldn't it be better to just pass the stuff you need inside the method, as argument?

```
process($i);

function process($i){
   echo $i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the function also you should declare the global variable.

```
function process(){
   global $i;
   echo $i;
}
```

Comment: -1 for suggesting the use of `global` when the answer is clearly to pass as an argument. The correct uses for `global` and `$GLOBALS` are few and far between, and this is almost definitely not one of them. Especially when the user states `Ive tried Global but this is not what I want`

Answer (score 1):

I tested this and it worked for me the way i believe you would like it to work

```
$i= 0;

if(1==2){
echo "In this part";
$i = 1;
} 
else{
echo "........";
 $i = 2;
}

function process(){
 global $i;
 echo $i;
}

process();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are defining the function and not calling it after the if-else block. you can define it anywhere but call this function after the if-else block simply like

```
if(....){
echo "In this part";
$i = 1;
} 
else{
echo "........";
$i = 2;
}    

process();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure it will work with $_GLOBALS. Try this code by playing with `$var` variable

```
<?php

$i= 0;

$var=0;

if($var==0){
   echo "In this part";
$GLOBALS["i"]=1;

}
else{
   echo "........";
$GLOBALS["i"]=2;
}

process();

function process(){
   echo $GLOBALS["i"];
}


?>
```